# Fatal error while usin gDoctirne ORM in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, doctrine

I am getting following error message when using Doctrine ORM in Codeigniter.

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttribute() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\giftshoes\system\database\doctrine\Doctrine\Record.php on line 1424
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0011  327560  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
2   0.0363  3210720 require_once( 'C:\xampp\htdocs\giftshoes\system\codeigniter\CodeIgniter.php' )  ..\index.php:116
3   0.0492  3922368 Welcome->Welcome( ) ..\CodeIgniter.php:201
4   0.0817  6234096 CI_Loader->model( ) ..\welcome.php:14
5   0.0824  6248376 Shoes->__construct( )   ..\Loader.php:184
6   0.0824  6248424 Doctrine_Core::getTable( )  ..\Shoes.php:5
7   0.0824  6248424 Doctrine_Connection->getTable( )    ..\Core.php:1080
8   0.0824  6254304 Doctrine_Table->__construct( )  ..\Connection.php:1123
9   0.0841  6396128 Doctrine_Table->initDefinition( )   ..\Table.php:249
10  0.0841  6397472 Shoes->__construct( )   ..\Table.php:301
11  0.0841  6397680 Doctrine_Access->__set( )   ..\Access.php:0
12  0.0841  6397680 Doctrine_Record->set( ) ..\Access.php:60
```

------------------Doctrine Table Definition-------------

```
abstract class BaseShoes extends Doctrine_Record
{
    public function setTableDefinition()
    {
        $this->setTableName('shoes');
        $this->hasColumn('sku', 'integer', 11, array('primary' => true, 'autoincrement' => false));
        $this->hasColumn('name', 'string', 255);
        $this->hasColumn('keywords', 'string', 255);
        $this->hasColumn('description', 'string');
        $this->hasColumn('manufacturer', 'string', 20);
        $this->hasColumn('sale_price', 'double');
        $this->hasColumn('price', 'double');
        $this->hasColumn('url', 'string');
        $this->hasColumn('image', 'string');
        $this->hasColumn('category', 'string', 50);
    }

    public function setUp() {

    }
}
```

------------------------Doctrine Table Code -------------------

```
class ShoesTable extends Doctrine_Table
{
    function getAllShoes($from = 0, $total = 15)
    {
        $q = Doctrine_Query::create()
        ->from('Shoes s')
        ->limit($total)
        ->offset($from);

        return $q->execute(array(), Doctrine::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
    }

}
```

-----------------Model Code-----------------

```
class Shoes extends BaseShoes
{
    function  __construct() {
        $this->table = Doctrine::getTable('shoes');
    }
    public function getAllShoes()
    {
        $this->table->getAllShoes();
    }
}
```

Comment: An incline as to which line is line 1424 would help.

Comment: Code is formatted now... 1424 is the line number of Doctrine\Record.php

Comment: Yes, but what is on that exact line number? Post the chunk of code immediately leading up to it.

Comment: Line 1424 to 1434

        if ($this->_table->getAttribute(Doctrine_Core::ATTR_AUTO_ACCESSOR_OVERRIDE) || $this->hasMutator($fieldName)) {
            $componentName = $this->_table->getComponentName();
            $mutator = $this->hasMutator($fieldName)
                ? $this->getMutator($fieldName):
                'set' . Doctrine_Inflector::classify($fieldName);

            if ($this->hasMutator($fieldName) || method_exists($this, $mutator)) {
                $this->hasMutator($fieldName, $mutator);
                return $this->$mutator($value, $load);
            }
        }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that :

- `Shoes extends BaseShoes` -- well, we can see that
- `BaseShoes extends Doctrine_Record`

`Doctrine_Record` has a `__construct()` method, which does a lot of stuff.

If you re-define the `__construct()` method in one of your classes, it will override the `__construct()` method that's defined in its parent class.

Here :

- your `Shoes::__construct()` method
- overrides `BaseShoes::__construct()`
- which itself doesn't exist, so is the same as `Doctrine_Record::__construct()`
- which seems to do some quite important Doctrine-related things ;-)

Not tested, but calling the parent's constructor in your own constructor could help :

```
class Shoes extends BaseShoes
{
    function  __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->table = Doctrine::getTable('shoes');
    }
    public function getAllShoes()
    {
        $this->table->getAllShoes();
    }
}
```

And, as a reference, quoting the [**Constructors and Destructors**][1] page of the PHP manual :

> **Note:**  Parent constructors are not called implicitly if the child class
> defines a constructor. 
> In order to
> run a parent constructor, a call to
> `parent::__construct()` within the
> child constructor is required.

Still, as a sidenote, I am not sure that defining your own constructor in a Model class, with Doctrine, is such a good idea -- and I've never seen this done, actually, as far as I remember...

And here's a [**blog-post on the Doctrine's blog**](http://www.doctrine-project.org/blog/doctrine-2-give-me-my-constructor-back), that seems to indicate I'm right *(quoting, emphasis mine)* :

> [...] someone asked about the
> constructor of entities in Doctrine 2
> and whether or not it could be used.
>
> I think this is something worth
> writing about since **in Doctrine 1
> this was not possible. The constructor
> was hi-jacked from you and used
> internally by Doctrine**.

And here's the section of Doctrine's 1.2 manual that's relevant : [**Overriding the Constructor**][3] :

> Doctrine doesn't allow you to override
> the `Doctrine_Record::__construct()`
> method but provides an alternative
>
> [...]